# Anyway to create an Oracle Database connection pool without pre-authentication?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, database-administration

I would like to incorporate database connection pooling in order to speed up the application (as opposed to creating a new connection each time), however, all the database pooling mechanisms require authentication at the time of the database pool creation (that I've tried).

If possible, I would like to create X database connections (which has gone through the expensive process of creating database connections but not yet authenticated yet).

Ideally the following...

```
myDatabaseConnectionPool.getConnection (userName, password)
```

which would not create a new database connection but simply authenticate against the database.  The database is Oracle so it would be okay to make the database pool Oracle specific.

Note:  This is a Java based web app.

Due to legacy design and previous decisions (out of my control), the web application of interest uses the user's credentials for database login (as opposed to a central login).  I cannot use a central user for the web application due to auditing reasons so each user has to have their own username/password in order to connect to the database (I know I know, I'm trying to work with what I am limited to).

Comment: Can you accommodate [proxy authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/proxya.htm) in your model? You'd still need the connection pool to authenticate as a single user (with few privileges, perhaps), but then each time you get a connection form the pool you can start a user-specific session?

Comment: I think this is possible with something like JNDI. [This tutorial lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#pooled_connection) seems to assume that's the normal use case. However I also wonder if it's possible to do this with third party connection pooling libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe such a thing is possible. Because a large part of the expense in connecting to the database is the authentication which happens on connecting to the database. In other words, you can't connect to the database without authenticating (unless your security policies are very lax).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say ... but as far as I know, their is no way to create Connection Pool without authentication.

You need to have administrator control ( i.e credentials ) to login in server and create Connection Pool (Which I know, it is not possible)

The only way left then, is to have the administrator username-password to create Connection Pool using JNDI Code

Am afraid but I don't think their is any other way than this.